# Will mysql_install_db delete existing databases?

Tags: mysql, homebrew

Using Homebrew on MacOS...

When starting mySQL using `mysql.server start` I receive the following error

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Tims-iMac.local.pid).
```

I've been reading lots of posts on how to solve this issue, none of which have worked, though I keep coming across the following advice:

```
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db
```

If I do this, will it delete all of my existing databases?

If it will delete them, how do I backup and restore the databases after a new mySQL install?

Comment: If you're concerned about data loss, **back up your system now** and verify these backups.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-install-db.html) the answer is no, it does not, however, as tadman suggests you should do a backup prior to performing any such maintenance.

To backup your databases use the [mysqldump command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).  And to restore you can use the [mysql command line tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).

Comment: I have quite a few databases; would just creating a copy of `/usr/local/var/mysql` work? Or do I need to go through each database and dump it?

Comment: Tried using `mysqldump` and got this: `Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect`

Comment: Is your MySQL server running?

Comment: You can actually dump all of the databases into one dump with MySQL dump or you could write a simple script that loops through the db names you wish to backup and generates separate files.  It is not recommended to copy directories as the dump will backup your databases and data 'safely'.

Comment: no, it's not running; I can't get it to start up. When doing `mysql.server start` I get the error shown in my question.